# Updating TFS 2013 Build Definition using Powershell v4

Tags: powershell, tfs

I need to update the build agent name on several build definitions in TFS. I was able to use my limited knowledge of powershell and create a script that has gotten me kinda close. The problem is that when the definition is saved all of other process params are getting cleared (i.e. Projects, Configurations, etc.).

I feel like I'm on the right track, but I'm just missing a piece or two of the puzzle. Here's what my script looks like:

```
$build1 = "build1.tfs.domain.com*"
$build2 = "build2.tfs.domain.com*"
$build3 = "build3.tfs.domain.com*"

add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll'
add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll'
add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll'
add-type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll'

$tfsCollectionUrl = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"
$server = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(New-Object Uri($tfsCollectionUrl))
$buildServer = $server.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$buildDefs = $buildserver.QueryBuildDefinitions("MyTeamProject")

foreach ($def in $buildDefs)
{
$processParams = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::DeserializeProcessParameters($def.ProcessParameters)

Switch ($processParams["AgentSettings"].Name)
{
    "TFSB1*"
    {
        Write-Host "Build definition name:" $build.Name
        Write-Host "Current build agent name:" $processParams["AgentSettings"].Name
        Write-Host "New build agent name:" $build1
        $processParams["AgentSettings"].Name = $build1 
    }
    "TFSB2*"
    {
        Write-Host "Build definition name:" $build.Name
        Write-Host "Current build agent name:" $processParams["AgentSettings"].Name
        Write-Host "New build agent name:" $build2
        $processParams["AgentSettings"].Name = $build2
    }
    "TFSB3*"
    {
        Write-Host "Build definition name:" $build.Name
        Write-Host "Current build agent name:" $processParams["AgentSettings"].Name
        Write-Host "New build agent name:" $build2
        $processParams["AgentSettings"].Name = $build2
    }
}

$def.ProcessParameters = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::SerializeProcessParameters($processParams)     
$def.Save()         
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer after getting the details wrong for a second time! (My sincerest apologies). I've tried doing the same thing that you have above now: altering the Build Agent named in the Process Parameters of a specific build definition. My attempt was successful, and I followed the exact same process that you have above, only for a single build def at a time. My first thought then is - do you have up to date Visual Studio SDK and Visual Studio Updates? My version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll (for example) is 12.0.30501.0, what is yours?

Comment: My version is 12.0.307230.0.

Comment: I noticed this behavior only occurred for build definitions with a version 12.0 process template, so I punted. Since we only have a handful of builds on that version, I just added a condition to skip those definitions and updated them manually. Here's the check I used: 
    `if ($def.Process.Version -eq "12.0") { # Write some info to a log }